# ScalaToolsSnapshots alternative resolver

Tags: scala, sbt

Can anyone please help me with the alternative to ScalaToolsSnapshots resolver currently listed in sbt._?

[XSBT](http://harrah.github.com/xsbt/latest/api/sbt/ScalaToolsSnapshots%24.html) states that it's deprecated from version 0.11.3 and suggests using an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scala-tools is no more, [the error message](http://scala-tools.org/) tells you how to resolve scala-tools snapshots in the future.

```
resolvers += "ScalaTools snapshots at Sonatype" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't lucky enough to get that error message, but now I know. Thanks again.