# sbt docbook plugin

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, docbook, typesafe-stack

I'm trying to port my maven-based docbook projects to sbt... but so far it is a nightmare :-(

Given the standard project directory:

```
mydoc
  + src
  |  + docbook
  |       + main.xml
  |       + chapter1.xml
  |       + chapter2.xml
  + project
  |  + plugins.sbt
  + build.sbt
```

... build.sbt looks like this:

```
name := "mydoc"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

docBookHtmlStyleSheet in DocBook := "http://mywebside.com/docbook/xhtml/docbook.xsl

docBookXslFoStyleSheet in DocBook := "http://mywebside.com/docbook/fo/docbook.xsl
```

... and finally project/plugins.sbt looks like this:

```
resolvers += ScalaToolsSnapshots

addSbtPlugin("de.undercouch" % "sbt-docbook-plugin" % "0.2-SNAPSHOT")
```

... I always get the following error:

```
[warn]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]      :: de.undercouch#sbt-docbook-plugin;0.2-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]      Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]              de.undercouch:sbt-docbook-plugin:0.2-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn]
[error] {file:/home/j3d/Projects/home/technotes_sbt/csharp-coding-guideliens/src/project/}default-3b0f83/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: de.undercouch#sbt-docbook-plugin;0.2-SNAPSHOT: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Any idea? Any help would be really appreciated. I'll try a bit further and then I'll give up.

Thanks,
j3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [original project](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/sbt-docbook-plugin) seems not to be maintained anymore and it uses 0.10.0 which maybe outdated for you.

There are [forks](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/sbt-docbook-plugin/network/members) out there, this is the [most recent one](https://github.com/jm2dev/sbt-docbook-plugin).

But must build yourself and publish it local.

By the way [ScalaToolsSnapshots is depricated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040427/scalatoolssnapshots-alternative-resolver).

Comment: OK... I think I'll keep maven and wait for stable, official sbt-docbook plugin. Thank you very much for you support ;-)